# nonatomic operations on std::atomic

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic

I have a huge array of pointers and I need to use them atomically. C++11 provides std::atomic class and relative functions for these purposes, and it is quite fine for me in general. But at the initialization and cleanup stages I do not need it to be atomic, it is known that only one thread will operate the data. It would be easy if atomic pointers would be implemented as plain volatile variables like it actually was before C++11, but now here is my problem: std::atomic forces me to use only atomic operations.
Is there a way of nonatomic use of std::atomic?

Comment: What is the _problem_ that you are trying to solve?  That is, what bad thing happens during initialization and/or cleanup that you think would not happen if you were not using std::atomic?

Comment: std::atomic and volatile are different things, designed for different purposes. Volatile does not imply atomic access. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to improve performance of the code and replace rather expensive atomic operations with cheap nonatomic ones.

Comment: I mean volatile is the required trait for the variables when atomic operations are carried by the specific functions like windows InterlockedCompareExchange that operates LONG volatile*.

Comment: You say you are trying to improve the performance of the code, but the only code you are proposing to change is "initialization and cleanup stages."  Have you measured the performance of those stages?  Is it actually a problem?

Comment: @yetanothercoder What makes you say that volatile is required for `InterlockedCompareExchange`?